# render fullcalendar and one backlog with just one json source

Tags: json, fullcalendar

I am using Fullcalendar with a backlog area where end-users can see and drag&drop events in/out from the calendar. The users can also filter by location, priority and responsible (and more...) the events he wants to see: this update the backlog and the calendar. This works great but so far the backlog and the calendar are updated through 2 different ajax calls. Consequently there is a latency when events appear on these 2 areas and the code is a bit more complex because I have to manage two flows of Json (on client and on server side) although they use the same parameters and the same database and table, not mention to the second MySQL connection cost :-). I would like to know whether it is possible to receive just one array of two Json through the Ajax call and use one to render the events on the calendar and use the other one to refresh the backlog list.

Here is the code I use:

```
            eventSources: [
                {
                    url: './ajax/_schedule_json.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: function() {
                        return {
                            location_id: $('#location_id').val(),
                            priority_id: $('#priority_id').val(),
                            responsible_id: $('#responsible_id').val(),
                            ...
                        };
                    },
                    success: function(data) {  },
                    fail: function(data) { }
                }
            ],
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually that is quite easy. Assuming that your script on server side generates an array of two json (events and backlog), you just need to open the file fullcalendar.js and search:

```
                success: function(events) {
                    events = events || [];
                    var res = applyAll(success, this, arguments);
                    if ($.isArray(res)) {
                        events = res;
                    }
                    callback(events);
                }
```

Modify the first and second lines as follow:

```
                success: function(json) { // Modified
                    events = json.events || []; // Modified
                    var res = applyAll(success, this, arguments);
                    if ($.isArray(res)) {
                        events = res;
                    }
                    callback(events);
                }
```

And then you can use the second json in your main javascript file:

```
            eventSources: [
                {
                    ...
                    success: function(data) { 
                        $.each(data.backlog, function (i, item) {
                            // do whatever you want with the backlog
                        });
                    }
                }
            ],
```